# main input error and delays when libvlc stream images in memory

Tags: opencv, vlc, libvlc

everyone!

I'm working on a project to stream images in memory with libvlc.For test, I stream camera frames. I have troubles here: first there are huge delays(about 7s), and the stream is very unstable.

It would be helpful if you can find some mistakes in my code!

I have these 3 errors repeated lots times .

**main input error: ES_OUT_SET_PCR is caaled too late(pts_delay increased to 692 ms)

main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called

avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow?)**

I'm especially curious about the last mistake: why is there a decoder error when I only want to encode some images?

And here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vlc.h>
#include <vlc_common.h>
#include <vlc_threads.h>
//#include <vlc/plugins/vlc_threads.h>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#define CAMERA_WIDTH 640
#define CAMERA_HEIGHT 480



vlc_mutex_t imem_get_mutex;
VideoCapture *g_camera;
int g_transport_number = 8080;



static int vlc_imem_get_callback(void *data, const char *cookie,
    int64_t * dts, int64_t * pts,
    unsigned *flags, size_t * size,
    void **output)
{
    //usleep(20000);
    Mat frame;
    vlc_mutex_lock(&imem_get_mutex);


    (*g_camera) >> frame;

    *output = malloc(frame.rows * frame.cols * 3);
    memcpy(*output,frame.data,frame.rows * frame.cols * 3);

    if (pts)
        *pts = 1;
    if (dts)
        *dts = 1;
    //  *size=(size_t)300;
    *size=(size_t)(frame.rows * frame.cols * 3);

    vlc_mutex_unlock(&imem_get_mutex);

    frame.release();

    return 0;
}

static void vlc_imem_release_callback(void *data, const char *cookie,
    size_t size, void *unknown)
{
    //  printf("release\n\n");

    free(unknown);
}


int main()
{
    vlc_mutex_init(&imem_get_mutex);

    g_camera = new VideoCapture(0);
    g_camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAMERA_WIDTH);
    g_camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    libvlc_instance_t * inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    char smem_options1[2000];
    char venc_options[1000];
//  sprintf(venc_options,"profile=baseline,level=3,keyint=50,bframes=3,no-cabac,ref=3,no-interlaced,vbv-maxrate=512,vbv-bufsize=256,aq-mode=0,no-mbtree,partitions=none,no-weightb,weightp=0,me=dia,subme=0,no-mixed-refs,no-8x8dct,trellis=0");
    sprintf(venc_options,"bframes=6,ref=6");

    sprintf(smem_options1,"#transcode{venc=x264{%s},vcodec=h264,vb=1000,fps=30,scale=0,width=640,height=480,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=http{mux=ts,dst=:%d/test}",venc_options,g_transport_number);
//  sprintf(smem_options1,"#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1000,fps=30,scale=0,width=640,height=480,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=http{mux=ts,dst=:%d/test},dst=display",venc_options,g_transport_number);

    char str_imem_get[100], str_imem_release[100],str_imem_data[100];
    sprintf(str_imem_get, "--imem-get=%ld", vlc_imem_get_callback);
    sprintf(str_imem_release, "--imem-release=%ld", vlc_imem_release_callback);
    //  sprintf(str_imem_data,"--imem-data=%ld",(long int)test_buffer);


    const char * const vlc_args[] = {
        "-I","dummy",
        "--ignore-config",

        "--demux","rawvideo",
        "--rawvid-fps","30",
        "--rawvid-width","640",
        "--rawvid-height","480",
        "--rawvid-chroma","RV24",

        "--imem-channels=1",
        "--imem-data=0",
        "--imem-cat=4",
        "--imem-fps=30",
        "--imem-codec=none",


        str_imem_get,
        str_imem_release,

        "--sout",
        smem_options1
    };

    inst = libvlc_new (sizeof (vlc_args) / sizeof (vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);
    m = libvlc_media_new_location(inst, "imem://");
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);
    libvlc_media_release (m);

    libvlc_media_player_play (mp);

    Sleep (200000); 

    libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);
    libvlc_media_player_release (mp);
    libvlc_release (inst);


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help and I'm sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem and discovered the issue was related to the DTS and PTS values I was using when capturing from a live source using OpenCV like you. I was calculating the DTS and PTS values in real-time to avoid the pts_delay increase, but then after about 5 seconds like you, the time between imem get function callbacks kept increasing. I then used a fixed frame rate value interval value like 33333 added each time. This fixed the lag issue, but resulted in the 1st error with the clock reset. The solution I found was to set DTS to -1 (unused), and set the value of PTS to libvlc_clock(). For example:

```
int MyImemGetCallback (void *data, 
    const char *cookie, 
    int64_t *dts, 
    int64_t *pts, 
    unsigned *flags, 
    size_t * bufferSize, 
    void ** buffer) 
{
    MyImemData* imem = (MyImemData*)data;

    if(imem == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(imem->mQuitFlag)
        return 1; // Exit

    if(imem->mFrameNumber == imem->mPrevFrameNumber)
    {
        return 0; // No new image data
    }

    // Update frame count information...
    imem->mPrevFrameNumber = imem->mFrameNumber;
    *dts = -1;
    // You can use libvlc_clock to avoid PCR reset and delays
    // on realtime data...
    *pts = libvlc_clock();

    *bufferSize = 
        imem->mOpenCvImage->rows * 
        imem->mOpenCvImage->cols * 
        imem->mOpenCvImage->channels();
    *buffer = imem->mOpenCvImage->data;

    return 0; // Success.
}
```

I know this was posted 6 months ago, but I came across the same problem today and figured somewhat else might too.